# Как реализовать закрытие работающей программы на языке C# в среде Microsoft Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, бот

У меня есть программа, которая при нажатии на кнопку начинает делать определенные манипуляции в браузере, т.е. кликать, водить мышкой и т.д. Но поскольку программа кликает, то сама форма находится в неактивном состоянии. Чтобы закрыть программу, я пробовал сделать хук и отлавливать это нажатие и тогда закрывать её, но это срабатывает не всегда, **и даже** если срабатывает, то форма закрывается, а сама программа(я смотрел в диспетчере задач, в этот момент она находится в фоновом режиме) продолжает ещё выполнять несколько действий и только когда довыполняет их закрывается. Есть ли какой-то более верный способ, который разом мог бы закончить выполнение всех скриптов и закрыть программу? (Если  можно сделать так, чтобы программа перестала кликать, но не закрывалось ещё лучше) В качестве кода для закрытия программы я использовал `Applicaton.Exit()`

Comment: Кажется, я уже видел этот вопрос

Comment: GetCurrentProcess + TerminateProcess попробуйте

Comment: Ну так сделайте поддержку отмены. Например раздайте всем частям программы общий CancellationToken. Для этого же оно и придумано. Или можете запустить работу в отдельном Thread и можете убить его, если вам уж так сильно хочется именно насильно все грохнуть.